# ScrollTo doesn't work correctly in Android emulator

Tags: java, android, appium

I created some Appium tests and successfuly run them on my real Android device.
Then I prepared Android emulator and run the tests again.

It seems that ScrollTo doesn't work correctly in the emulator - it doesn't go down through all "pages" to the certain text.

Is there any way to make Appium to list down all the screens until the bottom line?

Comment: please share your code. Would be easy to answer

Comment: I use like the following:  `driver.scrollTo("Lorem Ipsum");`   The text is on the next screen in case to scroll down. It  works on the real device, but fails on the emulator.